# Как настроить 301 редирект для html?

Tags: php, html, .htaccess, seo

У меня есть сайт, состоит из HTML страниц. Название домена - pas82.ru. Когда я делаю анализ сайта, выдает дубль главной страницы `index.html` и просто `/`. Пробовал сам настроить, ничего не вышло. Хотелось бы сделать переадресацию с `index.html` на pas82.ru. И еще переадресацию с www.pas82.ru на pas82.ru. Вот что на данный момент у меня в `.htaccess`:

```
AddDefaultCharset utf-8
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.pas82.ru[nc]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://pas82.ru/$1 [r=301,nc]

//301 редирект
Redirect 301 pas82.ru/index.html pas82.ru
```